# Spring slice test with OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to make same slice test (`@WebMvcTest`) but the context of application is failing to start.

I write a simple test:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = [FeedbackEndpoint, FeedbackTestConfig])
class FeedbackEndpointSliceSpec extends Specification implements SampleFeedbacks {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class FeedbackTestConfig {
        DetachedMockFactory detachedMockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

        @Bean
        FeedbackFacade feedbackFacade() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Stub(FeedbackFacade)
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    FeedbackFacade feedbackFacade

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc

    @WithMockUser
    def "asking for non existing feedback should return 404"() {
        given: "there is no feedback with the id I want"
        UUID nonExistingId = UUID.randomUUID()
        feedbackFacade.find(nonExistingId) >> { throw new FeedbackNotFoundException(nonExistingId) }

        expect: "I get 404 and a message"
        mockMvc.perform(get("/feedback/$nonExistingId"))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I've got an exception. I attach a stacktrace, I presume that it's caused by one of this annotation: `@EnableAuthorizationServer`, `@EnableOAuth2Client`, `@EnableResourceServer`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:50)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configurers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurer>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurer>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 32 more
```

I tried already `@WebMvcTest(value = [FeedbackEndpoint, FeedbackTestConfig], secure = false)`, but it didn't work either.

**EDIT**

In one topic on SO I found to add this annotation: `@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = true)` and... it's working, but is it ok to add this?

Comment: What happens if you add `@SpringBootTest` at the top of your test class?

Comment: @TwiN It's not my only test so I get this: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [pl.flexcode.analyticsprime.feedback.domain.infrastructure.mvc.FeedbackEndpointSliceSpec]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper)]```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `@OverrideAutoConfiguration` is no good as it may try to load whole application context to your turning your unit test to integration test.
You may be using `@EnableAuthorizationServer` in your     `@SpringBootApplication` runner class, so test context is trying to load config classes for spinning AuthorizationServer. Try moving it to external configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig {
}
```